# Swift concurrency. How to rethrow in catch block? Also about recursion in async/await

Tags: ios, swift, async-await, concurrency, swift-concurrency

First of all I have a function for get version from API.

```
func getVersionAsync() async throws -> VersionEntity {
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
        versionTask.getVersion { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let response):
                continuation.resume(returning: response.item)
            case .failure(let error):
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I need to handle it or repeat request after 5 seconds:

```
func checkVersion() async {
    do {
        let versionEntity = try await getVersionAsync()
        // handle versionEntity
    } catch {
        try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 5) <- Errors thrown from here are not handled
        await checkVersion()
    }
}
```

There is an error `Errors thrown from here are not handled`. What is the correct way to do this in swift concurrency?

Comment: You need another do/catch block inside of your catch block

Comment: Not related to your question, but that use of recursion worries me. What if the API call never succeeds and you keep trying every 5 nanoseconds? (And should that be 5 *seconds*?) Can/should the code be converted to a loop?

Comment: Rob C Thus I wouldn't can make a recursion. Geoff Hackworth it should be a recursion indeed.

Comment: If the version check throws, something somewhere is building an ever-expanding block of async execution contexts to eventually unwind all the await calls. My worry is that there is a finite limit on how bug that can get. It should be easy to test by removing the sleep and temporarily hacking `getVersionAsync` to always throw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add `throws` to the function signature so that the function exits if the `sleep` call throws an error. This for instance means that the functions exits if the surrounding `Task` is cancelled.

```
func checkVersion() async throws {
    do {
        let versionEntity = try await getVersionAsync()
        // handle versionEntity
    } catch {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5))
        try await checkVersion()
    }
}
```

Note that I changed the sleep to 5 seconds as that was the time given in the text.

If you don't want to use recursion then you could wrap the `do/catch` in a while loop. Here I also added a max tries parameter

```
func checkVersion(maxRetries: Int) async throws {
    var allDone = false
    var counter = 0

    while allDone == false {
        do {
            counter += 1
            let versionEntity = try await getVersionAsync()
            // handle versionEntity
            allDone = true
        } catch {
            if counter > maxRetries { return } // or maybe throw an error
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(5))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there’s an off-by-one error here with `maxTries`. Is it intended to be the number of tries, or the number of *retries*? I would choose retries so you don’t have to deal with it being zero and do nothing at all. There should always be at least one try. Just renaming the parameter maybe fixes the off-by-one error but I can’t quite work it out in my head!

Comment: @GeoffHackworth I can admit that I just wanted to include a limit but without testing it at all. I did look at it again and as far as I can see just renaming the parameter as you suggest will make the parameter work as intended. Thanks.

Comment: I have submitted an edit, but it is pending review. I also renamed counter as retryCount and moved where it is incremented to make it a little clearer

Comment: I changed to my own version even though they are pretty similar, I wanted the first recursive version to be as close as possible to the original code in the question so I didn't add a limit there,